# Ubuntu Server not mounting full harddrive

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on an old laptop to use a plex media server.
It is mostly working. I am however running into an issue where I am unable to use more than around 100 GB of the 1TB internal storage.

/dev/sda is showing 3 separate volumes: sda1, sda2, sda3

---

sda3 is the bulk of free storage but I'm unable to access it or use the space. It has been a very long time since I've operated entirely out of an ssh shell so any help would be appreciated. I'm willing to provide any necessary information.

I can SSH fully into the machine, and even move files using Transmit.

```
plexfamily@plex:~$sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 61.93 MiB, 64933888 bytes, 126824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 79.95 MiB, 83832832 bytes, 163736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 44.68 MiB, 46845952 bytes, 91496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 46.95 MiB, 49233920 bytes, 96160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E503645F-BB93-494E-8068-C2926E858FB9

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sda2  2203648    6397951    4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  6397952 1953521663 1947123712 928.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

---

```
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree  
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <928.46g <28.46g

LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 900.00g
```

I did attempt to extend the lv but it's still only showing me around 100G usable.

Comment: What does `pvs` and `lvs` print? Seems like your system is on a LVM with only 100GB allocated, /dev/sda3 being the underlying volume.

Comment: Command results added to original post

Comment: Interesting, did you do anything inbetween asking the question and now? Your lvm says `ubuntu-lv` is 900G while `fdisk` says it is 100G

Comment: I attempted to extend it. fdisk says 900 now as well. but when looking at df it still shows as almost completely full with a max of 100.

I'm attempting to move some files that will take it over that limit and see what happens

Comment: After attempting to move files it still failed when it maxed out the 100 GB

Comment: Alright, seems like you got your partition extended already, just need to extend the FS aswell now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition `/dev/sda3` is a LVM physical volume, added to the group `ubuntu-vg`, however your logical volume `ubuntu-lv` only uses 100G of the provided ~928G.

If you just want to use all this space for your root partition, you can use

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

According to the new information given, you extended the volume without resizing the file system (the `--resizefs` flag) so you have to run `resize2fs` manually.

```
resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

Comment: Solid, thanks. I knew it was something simple.