# Why does Ubuntu not use total LVM space?

Tags: 20.04, lvm

I have 4 x 4TB hard drives in Raid10 with a total space of 8TB. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I see the maximum space for the file system is 63GB. How do I expand it to reach the total capacity?

```bash
root@ubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               13G  2.3M   13G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   11G   83G  12% /
tmpfs                               63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop2                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop0                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  107M  1.7G   6% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                               13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1000
root@ubuntu:~# lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                      FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
loop0                     squashfs    61.9M /snap/core20/1328 
loop1                     squashfs    67.2M /snap/lxd/21835   
loop2                     squashfs    43.6M /snap/snapd/14978 
sda                                    7.3T                   
├─sda1                    vfat         1.1G /boot/efi         
├─sda2                    ext4           2G /boot             
└─sda3                    LVM2_member  7.3T                   
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4         100G /                 
sr0                                   1024M                   
root@ubuntu:~# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize PFree 
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  7.27t <7.18t
root@ubuntu:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree 
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- 7.27t <7.18t
root@ubuntu:~# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 100.00g
```

Comment: What does `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` print?

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize PFree 
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  7.27t <7.18t
root@ubuntu:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree 
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- 7.27t <7.18t
root@ubuntu:~# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 100.00g                                                    
root@ubuntu:~#

Comment: Please add this to your question. Its impossible to read in the comments section.

Comment: added to my question, thanks

Comment: I've written an answer to a question with the exact same problem recently, let me find it for your...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Server not mounting full harddrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417389/ubuntu-server-not-mounting-full-harddrive)

Comment: great now i see
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  7.2T   11G  6.9T   1% /
before /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   11G   83G  12% / 
so according to this result the new space 7.2T would be available to install web server and other app i will install, correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.