# Errno28: No space left on device

Tags: server, partitioning, ssd, disk-usage

I have an Ubuntu server that  stopped working this morning.
I logged in and found out that it was out of disk space.

Results of `lsblk` :

[image: ubuntu partitions]

Free space left:

[image: free space left]

I can see that the root partition is 100% full, and that's why the server stopped working, however I don't understand why my ex-sysadmin made a partition of 111GB when the drive had 223.6GB of total disk space.

What's the best thing I can do now? Is there any way to increase the space of the actual partition in a safe way without causing any damage to the files inside or the file-system?

Or is there any way that I can clone this SSD to a bigger SSD, however if I clone the SSD I think the problem will remain because the partition will have the same size, right?

Results of `df -h` :

[image: df -h command]

Results of `vgdisplay` :

[image: vgdisplay]

I can see that there is 111GB free space on the drive. How can I add it to the existing partition?

Comment: You can clean up disk space or resize a partition.

Comment: do you think this is safe and correct? the data wont be loss? if you have any other  better suggestion ...

Comment: I am not very familiar with lvm

Comment: thanks anyway for your help @Pilot6. I'll wait for someone who can point me in the correct direction

Comment: You may find this previous answer helpful: [Ubuntu Server not mounting full harddrive](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417392/178692). For more background on your setup, take a look at [Grow partition on ubuntu server 18.04 inside virtualbox doesn't seem to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698495/65304)

Comment: Do you have physical access to this server or is it a VPS?

Comment: Hi. I have physical access and im logged using putty, I tried the commands @steeldriver pointed me but i got the following error: write error failed: no space left on the device.
I understand this is happening because the drive is currently at 100%. 
Can someone point me of how can i delete some files that are not needed? temporary files? packages? don't know.. something like that. i feel i just need to free up a little space to get this resize comand working

Comment: @karel is there any folder that i can safely delete without compromising the working state of the ubuntuserver? i am still trying to figure it out the ls and cd commands, still searching for the delete command etc.

Comment: [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/57994/)

Comment: @karel thank you for pointing that out to me. I am running ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS do you think its safe to run the "sudo apt autoremove" command without risking loosing any valuable data i have on the server? i have mysql running inside the ubuntu server. thank you

Comment: I run `sudo apt autoremove` at least once a week without any problems. If you are able to update the software without getting package management error messages it is safe to run `sudo apt autoremove` otherwise if you are getting package management error messages you should solve them first.

Comment: @karel  damn, still no luck. im getting this error after running sudo apt autoremove: "Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to fill /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i with padding: No space left on device
you  have any other suggestion?

Comment: That's a bad error message. It means don't run `sudo apt autoremove`. Instead you should create additional storage space in your root partition first by adding the 111GB free space to it. **You can't do this while the root filesystem is in use!!!** Instead boot the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu and run the built-in GParted partition editor application from an Ubuntu live session. Here is a link: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/).

Comment: @karel thank you for the tip, do you think its best for me to clone the entire disk first? or the gpart is easy to use and shouldnt be a problem? thank you

Comment: Cloning a disk with errors on it clones the errors too. All the experts recommend that you should at least backup all of the data that is currently stored on a partition before resizing that partition.